# What apk format should I use for Amazon App Store for Kindle Fire tablet

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I've successfully created Android app using nativescript and angular. Now when I build, I am using Snapshot to create smaller size apk. What type of apk should I use to upload to the Amazon App Store?

I have:

```
app-arm64-v8a-release.apk
app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk
app-x86-release.apk
app-universal-release.apk
```

I uploaded the universal and it works, but it does take a while to download. Should I use one or more of the others? For the play store I am using Android App Bundle so it is one file of all.

Comment: Use 1.  app-arm64-v8a-release.apk
        2. app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk 3. app-x86-release.apk for playstore and amazon app store.

Comment: Now you will need to upload all built apk files in Google Play Developer Console. https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/publishing/android-abi-split#publishing-abi-split-apk